# Как отправить POST-запрос из php-файла?

Tags: post, php, http

Добрый день! Не могу понять почему не работает такой код (index.php):

```
function userRegister(){
    $fio = Flight::request()->data['fio'];
    $email = Flight::request()->data['email'];
    $lastuserid = getLastUserId();
    if($lastuserid > 9 || $lastuserid > 99){
        if($lastuserid > 99){
            $userid = '000'.($lastuserid + 1);
        } else {
            $userid = '0000'.($lastuserid + 1);
        }
    }else{
        $userid = '00000'.($lastuserid + 1);
    }

$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`fio`, `email`, `userid`) VALUES (:fio, :email, :userid)";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("fio", $fio);
    $stmt->bindParam("email", $email);
    $stmt->bindParam("userid", $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $db = null;

    $url = 'http://mysite.ru/gmail';
    $params = array('fio' => $fio, 'email' => $email, 'userid' => $userid);
    $query = http_build_query($params);

    $contextData = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Connection: close\r\n" .
            "Content-Length: " . strlen($query) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $query);

    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $contextData));

    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo $result;

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

}

При отправке формы данные уходят в index.php, который записывает их в базу и отправляет POST запрос на gmail.php. Как выяснилось в gmail.php не уходят параметры запроса. Так как echo пишет:

```
Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.
```

Если в gmail.php захаркодить email, то письмо на почту приходит, но без остальных параметров (то есть без fio и userid). Как это можно исправить? Или подскажите другой способ, хотя уже попробовал все примеры, которые нашел в сети (и с curl и с pecl - ничего не работает). Единственным вариантом вижу отсылать данные из index.php обратно странице через JSON и оттуда по аяксу делать POST-запрос на gmail.php, но это тот еще костыль.

Comment: предположу, что в $email лежит пустота (по каким-то причинам не проинициализровалась), поэтому оно и кодируется как `..&email&userid..`, и поэтому удаленный сервер не видит адреса.

Comment: Да. Так и есть. Дело в том, что я использую REST фреймворк и все запросы проходят через index.php, а оттуда уже мапятся дальше. Видимо нужно править htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

У меня ваш пример отработал корретно. Выдал единственный `Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in /var/www/xxxxx/test.php on line 19`

Так что, может, добавить header:

```
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
```

В остальном у меня php принял все тестовые данные.

Проверочный файл **`test.php`**:

```
<?php
$fio = 'f.i.o.';
$email = 'e m a i l';
$userid = 'user id';

$url = 'http://xxxxx.sergeisokolov.com/xxxxx/post.php';    
$params = array('fio' => $fio, 'email' => $email, 'userid' => $userid);
$query = http_build_query($params);

$contextData = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => "Connection: close\r\n" .
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($query) . "\r\n",
    'content' => $query);

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $contextData));

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $result;
```

И приемник **`post.php`**:

```
<?php
file_put_contents( 'post.txt', print_r( $_POST, TRUE));
echo 'OK';
```

В файл **`post.txt`** в итоге записывалось:

```
Array
(
    [fio] => f.i.o.
    [email] => e m a i l
    [userid] => user id
)
```

Comment: может быть переменные недоступны, которые я использую в $params? Обновил код, добавил полный код функции из index.php, которая обрабатывает форму.

Comment: Хотя нет, в том же блоке try они используются в самом начале при записи данных в базу и все нормально записывается.

Comment: Добавил content-type. Все так же.

Comment: А вот это `$db = null;` не обнуляет заодно $stmt и прибинденные к нему ваши парамерты?